# Laravel Model Parsing Array

Tags: laravel

I have an object in my database that I am trying to retrieve in the Model and parse through to display the text in the blade template. I am not quite sure how to get this to parse correctly. Thank you.

```
public function getStep1()
{
    $step1 = $this->details()->get();

    foreach($step1 as $step1)
    {
        $step1 = $step1->step_1;
        return $step1;
    }  
}
```

This gets me the following output that I don't know how to parse through. I have tried $step1[0], but that just gives me a [ nothing else.

```
[["$50,000-$100,000","More than $100,000"]]
```

My Blade template is simply this...

```
{{ $question->getStep1() }}
```

Thank you for your help.

**Update:**

When I do a var_dump, it says that my "steps" are stored as strings. Is that what's causing a problem? I still can't get within the [].

```
array (size=9)
      'id' => int 1
      'question_id' => int 55
      'step_1' => string '[["$50,000-$100,000","More than $100,000"]]' (length=43)
      'step_2' => string '[["Step2-option1","Step2-option2","Step2-option3"]]' (length=51)
      'step_3' => string '[["Step3-option2"]]' (length=19)
      'step_4' => null
      'step_5' => null
      'created_at' => string '2018-10-03 12:29:05' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2018-10-03 12:29:05' (length=19)
```

Comment: $step1 as $step1 will not work since they are the same variable name.  do $step1 as $step.  Then inside that if $step is an array you'll have to do another foreach loop to get the individual array indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning double array you can just append results to a temporary array and then return that array, check the example code:

```
public function getStep1()
{
    $tempArr = [];
    $steps = $this->details()->get();

    foreach($steps as $step1)
    {
        $tempArr[] = $step1->step_1;
    }

    return $tempArr;
}
```

Your template code should now iterate over an array we have built right now, so a foreach is required. Like below:

```
@foreach($question->getStep1() as $step)
// do something with $step
@endforeach
```

Comment: Update your question with `code from your blade view`

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of steps or just step 1? Im not sure from your question

Comment: From this update, I'm getting the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I'm just trying to get what's inside the "" ("$50,000-$100,000","More than $100,000"). Thank you.

Comment: Then you can access it with $step1[0][0] and $step1[0][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getStep1()
{
    $steps = $this->details()->get();
    $totalSteps = collect();
    foreach($steps as $step1)
    {
        foreach ($step1 as $step)
        {
             $toalSteps->push($step);
        }

    }
    return $totalSteps;
}
```